# Нужна ли запятая между "но" и "считая"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, деепричастный-оборот

Уж что там за ночная работа такая была у Светки, Таня могла только догадываться.
Но(,) считая себя особой воспитанной, деликатной и просветленной, неудобные вопросы она Свете не задавала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая нужна.

> **Примечание.** Для различных случаев употребления присоединительного союза в самом начале предложения устанавливаются следующие правила:
> **1)** если за союзом следует обособленный оборот (чаще всего — конструкция с деепричастием), **запятая** ставится после союзов ***и*** и ***но*** и не ставится после союза ***а***:
> ***И, задержавшись у выхода,** он обернулся; **Но, не желая возвращаться к сказанному,** докладчик это место своего сообщения пропустил; **А услышав эти слова,** он воскликнул…*

[Справочник Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#) (конец параграфа).

Answer (score 2):

Поддержу ответ *Александра* и дополню его примерами:

*Но, считая себя продвинутым юзером, я, конечно, с самого начала заподозрил подвох...* (О. Кашин. Коммерсантъ);
*Но, считая себя недостойным, все молился и молился* (В. Крупин. Стояние в молитве);
*Но, считая себя превыше всех, я оставался балаганным шутом...* (О. Немон. Реквием);
*Но, не считая себя знатоком лёгкой музыки и не подстрелив в своей жизни ни одного лося, дворецкий счёл за лучшее подойти к входной двери...* (П. Баккаларио. Синий. Сапфировая загадка);
*Но, представляя себя мысленно на смертном одре, ему легче было найти какую-то отправную точку...* (А. Ладинский. В дни Каракаллы).